# Get count and avg for specific criterias and also the rest

Tags: c#, linq

I have my data in the following format..

```
    UserId    Property1      Property2     Property3   Testval
    1         1              1             10          35
    2         1              2             3           45
    3         2              5             6           55
and so on..
```

I have several criterias, a couple of example are as below..

```
a) Where Property1=1 and Property3=10
b) Where Property1!=1 and Property2=5
```

What I need is the count of users & testval average who fall within these criterias and also of all the rest who do not.

So, result data structure would be as follows..

```
User Count

Criteria         Users     
a                100
b                200
rest             1000

TestVal Average

Criteria         avg    
a                25
b                45
rest             15
```

I know how to get the userlist for the specific criterias separately.

```
data.Where(w=>w.Property1==1).Select(s=>s.UserId).ToList()
```

But how do I get the usercount and avg val and more importantly the same for the rest of users.

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Try `data.Where(w=>w.Property1==1 && w.Property3==10 ).Average(r => r.Testval);`

Comment: if userId is unique then you can the get rest that does not exists in results from criterias a and b. a temp datatable sounds useful.

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki ok, but then how do I get the rest of the conditions and the rest who do not fall under any conditions in result data structure

Comment: @Badiparmagi y, userid is unique..

Comment: Are the criterias mutually exclusive? Probably yes, otherwise I don't see how you can define "the rest".

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm a little confused by the term "mutually exclusive".. The userlist generated by all the diff criterias would have diff users in them and no common users.. Is that what you wanted to know.. if something else plz   do ask again..

Comment: @Amab, Is it possible for a user to satisfy more than one criterion?

Comment: @SWeko No, it would never happen...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are seeking for **group by criteria**. Something like this:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x => 
    x.Property1 == 1 && x.Property3 == 10 ? 0 :
    x.Property1 != 1 && x.Property2 == 5 ? 1 :
    // ...
    -1)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Criteria = g.Key,
        Users = g.Count(),
        Avg = g.Average(x => x.Testval),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: oh.. ok and then Criteria=-1 gives me value for the rest.. is that so...

Comment: Yes. Of course you can use arbitrary number, or even strings like "a", "b", "rest" instead of 0, 1, ..., -1.

Answer (score 2):

To get the count/average for a specific criterion, it's easy

```
Func<MyUser, boolean> criterion1 = user => user.Property1==1;
var avg = data.Where(criterion1).Average(user => user.Testval);
var count = data.Where(criterion1).Count();
```

(this will enumerate the data twice, so if that's an issue, you can materialize the data before the calculations)

If you want to evaluate multiple criteria (and don't want to repeat this code as many times as there are criteria), you can put them in a dictionary, and loop over them:

```
 var criteria = new Dictionary<string, Func<MyUser, boolean>>{
    { "criterion1", user => user.Property1==1 },
    { "criterion2", user => user.Property1!=1 && user.Property2=5 },
    //...
 }

 foreach (var criterion in criteria){
   var avg = data.Where(criterion.Value).Average(user => user.Testval);
   var count = data.Where(criterion).Count();
   Console.WriteLine($"{criterion.Key} average: {avg}, count: {count}");
 }
```

You can also put the results in another dictionary, something like

```
 var results = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();

 foreach (var criterion in criteria){
   var avg = data.Where(criterion.Value).Average(user => user.Testval);
   var count = data.Where(criterion).Count();
   results.Add(criterion.Key, Tuple.Create(avg, count));
 }
```

and then make a better looking report, or you can even create a specific result class that will be easier to print after.

To get the rest (the count/average of the data that does not fit any predicate) you can loop through all the predicates, negating them;

```
var query = data;
foreach (var criterion in criteria.Values){
  query = query.Where(user => !criterion(user));
}
var restAvg = query.Average(user => user.Testval);
var count = query.Count();
```

Comment: Edited with calculation for the rest values.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it  using select new to return new anonymously typed objects which contains your criteria.

```
public void Test()
    {
        var list = new List<User>();
        list.Add(new User {UserId = 1, Property1 = 1, Property2 = 1, Property3 = 10, Testval = 35});
        list.Add(new User {UserId = 1, Property1 = 2, Property2 = 2, Property3 = 3, Testval = 45});
        list.Add(new User {UserId = 1, Property1 = 5, Property2 = 5, Property3 = 6, Testval = 55});

        Func<User, bool> crit = u => u.Property1 == 1 & u.Property3==10;
        var zz = list.Where(crit)
            .GroupBy(t => new {ID = t.UserId})
            .Select(w => new
            {
                average = w.Average(a => a.Testval),
                count = w.Count(),
                rest = list.Except(list.Where(crit)).Average(a => a.Testval)
            }).Single();
    }
```